# Error when running code

Tags: c++, text-files

I have tried the following code but I get an error when running it. I have used Debugger but I can't understand the errors in the call stack.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10][2],i,j, b[10],max, min;
    ifstream f("numere.txt");

    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=2;j++)
        {
            f>>a[i][j];
            b[i]=0;
        }
    }

    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=2;j++)
        {
            b[i]=b[i]+a[i][j];
        }
    }

    max=b[1];
    min=b[1];

    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        if(max<=b[i]) max=b[i];
        if(min>=b[i]) min=b[i];
    }

    cout<<"Cea mai mare suma este:"<< max<<endl;
    cout<<"Cea mai mica suma este:"<< min<<endl;


    f.close();
    return 0;

}
```

---

[image: Call Stack Screenshot]

Please, help me. I am a beginner and I have never worked with files before.

Comment: Can you post a sample input file?

Comment: You are going one out of bounds in your `for` loops, `i<=10` should be `i<10` and the same problem with `j`. Arrays in C++ start at `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least one error: array index out of bounds:

```
 for(i= 0;i<10;i++)
{   //^^^
    for(j=0;j< 2;j++)
    { //^^^
        f>>a[i][j];
        b[i]=0; //Why you put b[i] here??
    }
}
```

Since you declare `a[10][2]` and array indices start from `0`, not `1` in C++. You will access memory that does not belong to `a` (and `b`).

Comment: Thank you and also another error of the program was that I was comparing up to 5 numbers instead of 10.

Answer (score 2):

The first index in C++ array is **0**, not **1**.

Try to go from **0** to **9** in your loops, instead of from **1** to **10**.

You can get more information on C++ arrays [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).

Answer (score 1):

The first error that stands out here is you are starting your array accesses at `1` in C++ arrays indexes start at `0`, this also means that you are accessing out of bounds in your for loops as well, for example this:

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    ^^^  ^^
```

should be:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
```

accessing memory outside of what is allocated is undefined behavior and can result in anything even code that appears to work.